# Finding the smallest negative eigenvalue if the eigenvalues are complex

Tags: matlab, eigenvalue

I want find in matlab ,the smallest negative eigen value,from complex eigenvalues ,of a squaure matrix (5,5) with all the entries of the matrix are complex .The answer should be real value.So how can I do this im matlab?.

Comment: What makes you think there will be real valued eigenvalues?

Comment: the eigenvalues are complex, but when I choose in matlab the smallest one from the complex eigenvalues ,the answer is positive real because I use min(abs(eigenvalues)).And I the answer should be negative,because I need to use the negative of  this value.

Comment: You still have not defined precisely what you want. Complex numbers are not totally ordered so there is no min or max.

Comment: Here you hit the point ,how can I compare complex numbers to find the smallest negative one?

Comment: There's no such thing as a negative complex number.

Comment: I have negative complex eigenvalues.

Comment: No you do not. There is no such thing as a negative complex number. You can have negative real numbers. If you have 0 imaginary part then you have a real number which can be positive or negative.

Comment: `min(abs(eigenvalues))` does not give the smallest eigenvalue; it gives you the eigenvalue closest to the origin of the complex plane. You need to make clear what you mean by "smallest".

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you need?

```
min(real(eig(A)));
```

Comment: No,because this is wrong to select only the real part of the complex number.

Comment: In that case, What do you mean by "smallest negative eigenvalue" and "the answer should be real value:?

Comment: How can I compare complex numbers to find the smallest negative one?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to find the complex number which has the smallest real part? For instance if you have [-5+4i, -2+3i, 10-12i] you want -5+4i

Comment: Here is the question,how can I compare complex number?

Comment: This is more a math question than a programing question... You can compare their real part, or the modulus...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare complex numbers. At most, you can compare the magnitudes of complex numbers.So, `min(abs(eig(A)))` is the right answer. If you need the negative of this value, just tack on a negative sign